# When using Composer to install Magento extension, should I use Command Prompt to connect my local computer with remote server first?

Tags: composer-php, localhost, magento2

I am new to Magento and never expected installing Magento extension to be so complicated.
I previously use WordPress and installing a WordPress plugin is simply uploading in its dashboard.
I have already installed php.exe and Composer on my computer, it is Windows.
And I have watched several YouTube tutorial on installing Magento extension with Composer, and didn't quite understand.

1. I suppose the first step is to open Windows Command Prompt and connect my local computer to my remote server. I did not see this step in the tutorial.
2. Second step, I think is to come to the folder where my Magento store is installed. In this folder, there is one doc named as "composer.json".
3. I think it comes to the steps of installing extension as showed in tutorial.

I have no technical background and it is my first time of using Composer, therefore, I didn't understand many things.
i tried to follow their tutorial, but it seems quite different.
In my Windows Command Prompt, it startes with my C disk and my computer user name.
However, in the tutorial, it seems to be their username @ their server address.